# Zerostack headset fit

Tags: headset

I am looking to get a ZeroStack headset upper and have found the right size in terms of diameters.  However, different models of headset reach different depths into the cup on the frame.  Should the headset depth fit the cup perfectly?  Is it acceptable for the headset to not reach the bottom of the cup?

[image]

The frame is an Orange Elite 2012. The depth is approximately 12mm.

Comment: Is it fully integrated or semi-integrated?  In English:  Do the bearing cartridges sit in the frame itself, or are there frame manufacturer provided races that sit between the headtube and bearing races?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  The frame is an Orange Elite, and was not supplied with any separate races.  I only think it is zero stack because I used the cane creek headset finder.

Comment: Take a picture and show us.  If possible try and find some model number or other identifiers on the headset, so we can properly identify it.

Comment: Hmm, the photo doesn't tell us much, it could easily be none integrated.  Can you post a picture of the headset (preferably with all the markings visible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a semi integrated head tube to be used with semi integrated head set, a fully integrated head tubes machining is different , it would have a precis depth and an 45 degree angle to it , in order to match fully integrated bearings and yield a exact final bearing depth . When useing a semi integrated system the cup or race you press into the head tube takes the place of this precision machining of the head tube.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been shopping for headsets and now believe you don't *need* to go all the way down, but longer is better.

Answer (score 0):

The exact model is a Cane Creek 5 Zero Stack Tapered.  I got this information from the Orange website (www.orangebikes.co.uk/bikes/archive/2012/elite_pro/), although as it isn't advertised on Cane Creek's website I would assume that it is an OEM product.  You will need to get the dimensions so you can buy an alternative.

I have to say though normally  for integrated headsets that have become worn all you need to do is read off the bearing manufacturer code (laser etched onto the outer race usually), and find a replacement.